# Python, How to break out of multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading

I am following one of the examples in a book I am reading ("Violent Python"). It is to create a zip file password cracker from a dictionary. I have two questions about it. First it says to thread it as I have written in the code to increase performance but when I timed it (I know time.time() is not great for timing) there was about a twelve second difference in favor of not threading. Is this because it is taking longer to start the threads? Second if I do it without the threads I can break as soon as the correct value is found by printing the result and the entering the statement exit(0). Is there a way to get the same result using threading so that if I find the result I am looking for I can end all other threads simultaneously?

```
import zipfile
from threading import Thread
import time

def extractFile(z, password, starttime):
    try:
        z.extractall(pwd=password)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        z.close()
        print('PWD IS ' + password)
        print(str(time.time()-starttime))

def main():
    start = time.time()
    z = zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip')
    pwdfile = open('words.txt')
    pwds = pwdfile.read()
    pwdfile.close()
    for pwd in pwds.splitlines():
        t = Thread(target=extractFile, args=(z, pwd, start))
        t.start()
        #extractFile(z, pwd, start)
    print(str(time.time()-start))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: I would also recommend you to check out other implementations of the Python interpreter such as [Stackless](http://stackless.com/) and [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) which lets you take advantage of concurrent programming. However, this is not always the fastest solution.

Answer (score 2):

In CPython, the Global Interpreter Lock ("GIL") enforces the restriction that only *one* thread at a time can execute Python bytecode.

So in this application, it is probably better to use the `map` method of a `multiprocessing.Pool`, since every try is independant of the others;

```
import multiprocessing
import zipfile

def tryfile(password):
    rv = passwd
    with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip') as z:
        try:
            z.extractall(pwd=password)
        except:
            rv = None
    return rv

with open('words.txt') as pwdfile:
    data = pwdfile.read()
pwds = data.split()

p = multiprocessing.Pool()
results = p.map(tryfile, pwds)
results = [r for r in results if r is not None]
```

This will start (by default) as many processes as your computer has cores. If will keep running `tryfile()` with a different passwords in these processes until the list `pwds` is exhausted, gather the results and return them. The last list comprehension is to discard the `None` results.

Note that this code could be improved to stop shut down the `map` once the password is found. You'd probably have to use `map_async` and a shared variable in that case. It would also be nice to load the zipfile only once and share that.

Comment: I would suggest using `with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip') as z`, avoiding the else: z.close()

Answer (score 1):

This code is slow because python has a [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock), which means only one thread can execute at a time. This causes multithreaded code to run slower than serial code in Python. If you want to create a truly multithreaded application, you'd have to use the [Multiprocessing Module.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)

To break out of the threads and get the return value, you can use `os._exit(1)` First, import the os module at the top of your file:

```
import os
```

Then, change your `extractFile` function to use `os._exit(1)`:

```
def extractFile(z, password, starttime):
    try:
        z.extractall(pwd=password)
    except:
        pass
    else:
        z.close()
        print('PWD IS ' + password)
        print(str(time.time()-starttime))
        os._exit(1)
```